# SMFL library not loaded error in Mac OS BigSur

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml, macos-big-sur

Hello I have installed SFML in my M1 chip Bigsur using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOyp5n2FmZY and also fixed all the error related to M1 chip.But when I run my project I get this pop ups.
[popups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYV85.png)

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/../Frameworks/vorbisfile.framework/Versions/A/vorbisfile
> Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/sfml-audio.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-audio
> Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
> /Library/Frameworks/vorbisfile.framework/Versions/A/vorbisfile: code signature in (/Library/Frameworks/vorbisfile.framework/Versions/A/vorbisfile) not valid for use in process using Library Validation: library load disallowed by system policy

It even showed pop ups for every frameworks I went to settings and gave allow for each of them. But it kept on showing same popup how can I solve this problem in BigSur

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find that the library in question has been quarantined by the operating system. I would suggest:

- confirm the quarantine flag `ls -l@ /path/to/library-or-library_bundle`
- remove the quarantine flag `sudo xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/library-or-library_bundle`

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to your system preferences, then `Security & Privacy`. On `General` you see the settings for `Allow apps downloaded from:`. If you have a message like the one you have mentioned above, it says here `"your.framework" was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer` with a button `Allow Anyway` next to it. Click it.